# Pulling a random php file using getTemplate

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull a random add into a page.
I can pull this

```
<? getTemplate('sideadd.php'); ?>
```

But if I want to pull
sideadd1.php / sideadd2.php

randomly, I thought I would be able to do this.

```
<? getTemplate('sideadd '.rand(1,2).' .php'); ?>
```

But unfortunately I can't. it returns nothing.

So what's the best way of going about this.
Pretty new to php so sorry if I dont explain myself very well.

Comment: Are you sure the file should be named "sideadd 1 .php" (with spaces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<? getTemplate('sideadd '.rand(1,2).' .php'); ?>
```

to:

```
<? getTemplate('sideadd'.rand(1,2).'.php'); ?>
```

You were generating 'sideadd 1 .php', instead of 'sideadd1.php'

Comment: you better use `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: Great. thanks alot, I was starting with code that pulled a .jpg and it had spaces.